# Select из картинок

Tags: javascript, php, html, form

Всем добрый день! Имеется допиленный select с выбором картинок из БД по id, но вот как передать значение ID картинки через форму html post увы уже не могу сообразить, вернее подставить в форму в input type=hidden значение переменной c id картинки.Задача передать через html форму в переменной POST id картинки

```js
<script>
    $(function(){
    $('.photo-options img').click(function(){
        $('.photo-options img').attr('class', '');
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        $('.result').html('' +  $(this).attr('id'));
    })
})

</script>
```

```css
.photo-options{
    float: left;
    width: 450px;
}

.photo-options img{
    width: 200px;
}

/*make css for active option image here*/
.photo-options .active{ 
    border: 2px solid blue;
    border-radius: 5px;
}


.result{
    float: left;
    width: 450px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="photo-options">

    <?php
require 'connect.php';
if($_POST['detal'])
{
$id=$_POST['detal'];
$sql=mysql_query("select * from `chertesh` left join `cena` on `cena`.`cher` = `chertesh`.`id` where `chertesh`.id  = '$id' order by `cena`.`id_cena`");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
$translate=$row['translate'];
$operaciya=$row['operaciya'];
$esk=$row['esk'];

echo '<p><a href="javascript:void(0)">
<img id="'.$operaciya.'"  alt="'.$translate.'" src="'.$esk.'.jpg"></a>
</p>';
}
}
?>
</div>
<div class="result">
```

Comment: input type="hidden"  id="<? echo $id?>"

Comment: @DrMcSheen увы, изнчально и хотел использовать hidden. но так и не смог понять как из скрипта js передать переменную с ID картинки взятую из mysql и вставить в hidden)я понимаю что вопрос вероятно выглядит банальным, но не когда еще всталкивался с подобной связкой

Comment: а где вообще форма? где этот hidden? покажи код

Comment: @DrMcSheen форма, обычный html <form method="post"  id="form2" action = "indexotk3.php"> 
<input type="hidden" name="detal" value="<?php echo  "$id";?>">
<input type="hidden" name="oper" id="<? echo $result?>">
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" value="Добавить в журнал" />

Comment: @DrMcSheen https://jsfiddle.net/freakrock/xsuoy0t5/

Comment: `<?php echo "$id";?>` вот тут кавычки не нужны,иначе строка ломается